# Как сделать чтение нескольких структур и одной переменной из бинарного файла?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, binary

Формат файла состоит из 3 структур и одной переменной. Подробное описание формата во вложении, просьба посмотреть его. У меня возникла проблема, я не знаю как его читать. Дело в то что начало 5 байт - Идентификатор
Файла-карты для программ различных версий. Дальше идет структура - 32 байта, дальше переменная 4 байта, дальше опять идет структура, она может быть одна, а может и 100 штук - размер одной 47 байт, далее идет следующая структура, ее размер 614 байт, она также может быть одна или несколько или вообще не быть, как читать этот бинарный файл не пойму. Подробности структуры и т.д. в файле, который находится в приложении.Вот код и попытки... По не понятной причине не работает(

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef   unsigned  int Cardinal;
typedef   unsigned char byte;
typedef   unsigned  short word;
typedef   bool boolean;
typedef   int LongInt;
struct Cod
{
   unsigned char WayPointType : 2;
   //разряды 1-0 – признак «Начало/конец участка»:
   //«0» - середина участка,
   //«1» - начало участка,
   //«2» - конец участка
   unsigned char ChannelNum : 2;
   //разряды 5-2 – код частоты радиоканала
   unsigned char isCrossRoad : 1;
   //разряд 6 – признак скрещивания участков «Перекресток»:
   //«0» - отсутствует скрещивание,
   //«1» - участки скрещиваются.
   unsigned char CoordChanged : 1;
   //разряд 7 – признак «Изменение координаты»:
   //«0» - возрастание орд-ты по нечетным путям,
   //«1» - возрастание орд-ты по четным путям.
};

struct TypeFile
{
   byte ByteC;
   byte ByteN;
   byte ByteS;
   byte ByteT;
   byte Byte2;
};

struct  Zagolov
{
   Cardinal Naprav;
   Cardinal Sdvig;
   byte ShiftLat;
   byte ShiftLong;
   word CountKm;
   byte Rezerv[20];
};

struct InfoFile //614 chunk
{

   LongInt LinAddr;//LinAddr: LongInt      {линейная координата объекта}
   byte Tip;//Tip: byte            {тип объекта: см. таблицу ниже по тексту}
   byte Road;//Road: byte          {путь, которому принадлежит объект}
   char Nazvanie[8];//Nazvanie: array[1..8] of char   {название (имя) объекта}
   word SGreen;

   byte SYellow;//SYellow: byte
   /*{допустимая скорость проезда препятствия. Для объекта  «Проба тормозов» - скорость начала торможения}*/
   byte Uklon;//Uklon: byte    {значение несущей частоты АЛСН}
   word Width;//Width: word    {длина объекта. Для объекта  «Проба тормозов» - расчетный тормозной путь}
   word Uklon2;

   word En_Speed[6][49];
   //En_Speed: array [1..6,1..49]of word; массив ограничений скорости движения по новой таблице АЛС-ЕН.
   LongInt Id;//Id: LongInt            {относительный указатель на другой объект 500-м участка}
   //абсолютный адрес объектов = Pos2 + Id.
   //Если Id=-1, тогда у 500-метрового участка больше нет  объектов  }

};

struct zagkm
{
   Cardinal LinCoord;
   LongInt geosh;
   LongInt geodl;
   boolean Enabled[30];
   LongInt ID;
   Cod Cod_;
};

Zagolov zagolov;
int Pos2;
zagkm* chunk47;
InfoFile* chunk614;
const int zagkmBegin = sizeof(TypeFile)+sizeof(Zagolov)+sizeof(Pos2);

int main() {
   ifstream is;
   is.open("2.map", ifstream::binary);
   if (!is.bad()) {
      // get length of file:
      is.seekg(0, is.end);
      int length = is.tellg();
      is.seekg(0, is.beg);
      //
      is.seekg(sizeof(TypeFile), is.beg);
      is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&zagolov), sizeof(zagolov));
      is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&Pos2), sizeof(Pos2));

      int InfoFileCount = (length - zagkmBegin - zagolov.CountKm*sizeof(zagkm)) / sizeof(InfoFile);
      int  checker = zagkmBegin + zagolov.CountKm*sizeof(zagkm);
      cout << "sizeof(zagkm)=" << sizeof(zagkm) << endl;
      cout << "sizeof(InfoFile)=" << sizeof(InfoFile) << endl;
      cout << "Pos2=" << Pos2 << endl;
      cout << "zagolov.CountKm=" << zagolov.CountKm << endl;
      cout << "checker=" << checker << endl;
      cout << "length=" << length << endl;

      is.seekg(zagkmBegin, is.beg);

      zagkm* chunk47 = new zagkm[1/*zagolov.CountKm*/];
      for (int i = 0; i < zagolov.CountKm; i++)
      {
         is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&chunk47[0/*i */]), sizeof(zagolov));
         //just do it
         //...
         cout << "zagkm[" << i << "]={\n";
         cout << "LinCoord=" << (LongInt)chunk47->LinCoord << ";\n";
         cout << "geosh=" << (LongInt)chunk47->geosh << ";\n";
         cout << "geodl=" << (LongInt)chunk47->geodl << ";\n";
         cout << "//Enabled[30];\n";
         cout << "ID=" << chunk47->ID << ";\n";
         cout << "//Cod_;\n";
         cout << "};\n";
      }


      is.seekg(Pos2, is.beg);

      InfoFile * chunk614 = new InfoFile[1/*InfoFileCount */];
      for (int i = 0; i < InfoFileCount; i++)
      {
         is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&chunk614[0/*i */]), sizeof(zagolov));
      }


      is.close();
      system("PAUSE");
      delete[] chunk47;
      delete[] chunk614;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

[Описание формата две карты для тестов кода](https://yadi.sk/d/x8YD1UD-otfFC)

Comment: "Не работает" бывает разным. Ради интереса посмотрите sizeof() ваших структур и сравните с тем, что должно быть. Еще очень помогает в отладчике смотреть на память, выделенную под стрктуру во время записи в ее поля значений.

Comment: Размер моих структур соответствует заданному формату, но ранее я не разу этого делал, а на практике задали

Comment: Не считывает просто ничего

Comment: ЕЩЕ РАЗ: sizeof() ваших структур и сравнивайте его с тем, что должно быть.

Comment: sizeof() моих структур соответствует формату.Даже вывод есть в коде:cout << "sizeof(zagkm)=" << sizeof(zagkm) << endl;
cout << "sizeof(InfoFile)=" << sizeof(InfoFile) << endl;

Comment: Выводит все верно 614 и 47 байт соответственно

Comment: Тогда можете брать в руки отладчик и отлаживать программу.

Comment: И как ее отладить ? Запускаю отладчик, программа выполняется, ошибок в VS нету

Comment: Значит, никак. Пришло время учиться отлаживать программы.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, с чего начать(

Comment: С чего попроще начать. Сортировка, игра-угадайка и так далее. Английский заодно. Без минимальных навыков работы в отладчике и знаний языка придется писать все за вас.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что тут, боюсь, придется все писать за автора.

Comment: Язык я более менее знаю, спросил что не так  коде, вы ничего по делу не ответили(

Comment: Может, Вам было бы проще если весь файл был бы уже считан в блок памяти? Под Windows это легко организовать используя Memory-Mapped Files. См. пример из моего старого ответа [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3588475/315935).

Comment: Вам все-таки необходимо научиться находить ошибки в программах (с отладчиком или без - неважно). Отладка (= заставить программу правильно работать) - одна из основных составляющих работы программиста (на любом языке и для любого типа решаемых задач). Процесс отладки предполагает локализацию проблемы. Сейчас получается, что Вы получили условие задачи и реализовали решение. Решение оказалось не работоспособным и Вы предлагаете другим во всем это разобраться. Шансов получить желаемый ответ у Вас немного. Если бы проблема была локализована, то вопрос был бы конкретнее (или Вы сами бы нашли ответ).

Answer (score 5):

Изучите выравнивание полей и паковку структур:

- [`#pragma pack(push, 1)` + `#pragma pack(pop)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2e70t5y1.aspx) - MSVS, gcc
- [`__attribute__((packed))`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Type-Attributes.html) - Gcc

Вот вам отличная статья в помощь: https://habrahabr.ru/post/142662/

Это первое. Второе, для типов фиксированных размеров используйте `uint8_t/uint16_t/uint32_t/uint64_t` и то же самое для знаковых, но без `u` в начале.

Третье, при чтении структур `zagkm` в качестве размера указываешь `sizeof(zagolov)`, что в корне неверно. Причём, если бы ты глазами проанализировал бы сам файл, ты бы увидел, на в первой записи стоят `FF FF FF FF` для значения `ID`, что дало бы для `LongInt` (`int32_t`) значение -1, а у тебя 0 выводится. Не смутило? Потом уже ползут все данные. Аналогичная хрень у тебя при чтении `InfoFile`. Что бы от такого не сильно страдать, куда лучше было-бы что-то вроде: `sizeof(chunk47[i])`, в случае рефакторинга тоже поможет.

Дальше уже сам разберёшься. Но, резюмируя:

1. Используй единый стиль кодирования: у тебя часть структур названо маленькими буквами, часть в CamelCase. То же самое касательно переменных. Либо не проси потом помочь разобраться - прояви уважение к людям.
2. Не используй непонятных сокращений. Что это за zag???
3. Не используй транслитерации: если даже в спеке так, опиши понятно, но в комментарии сделай отсылку к спецификации. Раз уж какие-то деятели так сделали.
4. Не используй типов из других языков. Я вот писал, когда-то дааааааавно на Pascal, но не сходу вспомнил, что такое `Cardinal`. Для описания структур, в которых по спекам поля имеют фиксированный размер соответствующие типы (как писал выше про `XintYY_t`)
5. Не забывай про выравнивание и паковку при работе с бинарными форматами. А то перенесёшь файл на другую машину, а он там не откроется, а потом да на этом вашем x86_64 ничего не работает!
6. Не используй копипасту. Третье наблюдение моё (выше), явно вызвано именно ею.
7. Включи предупреждения!
8. Для проверки правильности размеров структур используй `static_assert()` или вариант его реализации для C++03, если нет возможности использовать C++11
9. Для динамических массивов используй вектор. Постарайся избегать работы с сырыми указателями. Здесь это не проблема, даже `delete[]` правильно вызывается, но всё же.