# Как открыть и записать из бинарного файла массив структур

Tags: c++, массивы, файлы, struct, структуры

Есть данная программа, в которой вводятся поля для каждой структуры из массива, потом весь массив записывается в бинарный файл, вопрос в том, как реализовать обратную программу, то есть чтобы она открывала этот файл и создавала новый массив из структур.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct contact
{
    char sname[50];
    char number[11];
    char adress[50];
};

const int m = 2;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    contact a[m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cin >> a[i].sname;
        cin >> a[i].number;
        cin >> a[i].adress;
    }
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("input.dot", "wb");
    fwrite(a, sizeof(contact), m, f);
    fclose(f);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: вы не знаете как читать из файла, или создавать массивы?

Comment: приведите пример кода, что у вас есть, ваш вопрос в таком виде неясен и ответить на него невозможно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение в стиле С++. Так как ваша структура является [POD](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85), можно сделать так:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

struct Contact {
    char number[11];
    char adress[50];
    char sname[50];
};

int main() {
    // открываем файл на чтение
    std::ifstream fin("file_name", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary); 

    // здесь будем хранить считанные структуры
    std::vector<Contact> vec; 

    // временная переменная
    Contact temp;

    // пока есть что читать, цикл продолжается
    while (fin.read((char*)&temp, sizeof(Contact))) {
        // запихиваем в конец вектора считанную структуру
        vec.push_back(temp);
    };

    // не забудем закрыть файл
    fin.close();
}
```

Comment: а потом перенесёте на 64/32 бит и... вдруг, поломается. Не делайте так. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/493617/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0/493666#493666 и то нюансы есть.

Comment: @MonahTuk а что в данном конкретном случае поломается? я просто никак в толк не возьму

Comment: Никто не мешает компилятору добавить падинги, что бы адреса были кратны. Кратность на 32 бит - 4 байта, на 64 - 8. Соответственно поползёт размер структуры, как следствие - корректность читаемых данных. В данном примере, т.к. поля байтовые, компилятор, скорее всего забъёт и будет всё хорошо и так (суммарный размер будет 111 байт). Но в общем случае - может не повезти. Каков, например, размер этой структуры: `struct Foo {char a; uint64_t b; };`? Поэтому, если и стоит речь о вычитке данный прямо в структуру, то нужно применять паковку, жертвуя скоростью.