# Считать данные из бинарного файла

Tags: c++, qt, потоки-данных

Есть бинарный файл. Его структура такова:

```
Сдвиг, байт        Тип данных
--------------------------------
 0                   long
 4                   long
 8                   long
 12                  short
 14                  short
 16                 unsigned char                    
 17                  char
```

Мне необходимо считать каждый тип данных в отдельный массив. Пытался делать это так:

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
struct data_star
{
    long  NSAO;
    long alpha;
    long beta;
    short ualpha;
    short ubeta;
    unsigned char mv;
    char sp;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
QFile file("C:\\Users\\Shmeisser\\Documents\\catalog\\SAO.CAT");

if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    QMessageBox::information(NULL, "show", "Failed to read");
    return 0;
}

QDataStream stream(&file);
stream.setByteOrder(QDataStream::LittleEndian);
data_star star1;
stream >> star1.NSAO;
stream >> star1.alpha;
stream >> star1.beta;
stream >> star1.ualpha;
stream >> star1.ubeta;
stream >> star1.mv;
stream >> star1.sp;
```

Но, как оказалось `QDataStream` не поддерживает оператор `>>` для типа данных `long`. Значит нужно перегружать оператор? Или можно выполнить задачу по-другому? Хотя бы и средствами только C++. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Так у вас файл бинарный или текстовый? А то в заголовке одно, в вопросе совсем другое...

Comment: @Harry бинарный

Comment: Вы использовали `#pragma pack(push,1)` в расчете разом считать структуру из файла?

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalian размер моей структуры не соответствовал 18 байтам, как должно быть. нагуглил, что исправить это можно таким образом.

Comment: Читайте как @Harry предложил, без лишнего разбора, раз у вас структура соответствует лейауту файла.

Comment: На всякий случай `long` в описании структуры можно заменить на `int32_t`, `short` на `int16_t`, и т.д. (для гарантии их размера).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если он и в самом деле бинарный, то

```
ifstream in(name,ios::binary);
data_star d;
in.read((char*)&d,sizeof(d));
```

и не мучьтесь...

Comment: `&d` преобразовать к `char*` надо бы.

Comment: @Harry Спасибо. Ещё один вопрос. А как теперь записать все прочитанные данные в массивы по каждому типу данных? Извините за глупые вопросы, просто никогда не работал с бинарными файлами и не очень понимаю логику.

Comment: @bronstein87 Простите, не очень понял ваш вопрос. Можно сделать массив структур - вы это хотите?

Comment: @alexolut Да, подправил

Comment: @Harry в этом бинарном файле около 250 тысяч записей, выведя структуру, полученную путем написанного Вами выше кода, я получил, что в `long  NSAO`(которая является порядковым номером) находится число `255622`. Судя по всему в эту структуру была записана последняя запись. А мне нужно вывести в массивы по каждому типу данных информацию от начала и до конца. Да, судя по всему необходим массив структур.

Comment: Нашёл решение с использованием вектора. Оно подходит?:  [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/500682/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80)

Comment: @bronstein87 Да, вполне можно поступить таким образом. Второй вариант - если количество записей меняться не будет - можно выделить память сразу под весь массив (посмотреть на размер файла, поделить на размер записи и узнать, сколько там записей) и считать весь файл целиком.

Comment: @Harry спасибо, всё получилось

Comment: @bronstein87 Ну, если ответ был полезен и исчерпывающ, ставьте птичку :)