# Не читаются структуры из бинарного файла

Tags: c

В русском stackoverflow есть решение на C++ ([Как открыть и записать из бинарного файла массив структур](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/500682/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80)), но как я выяснил из английского стэка (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605839/c-and-c-file-i-o), файловый ввод-вывод в C++ медленнее чем в C (на своем ноутбуке в этом я убедился). Поэтому хочу понять как читать данные из бинарного файла используя `stdio.h`.

Я записываю в бинарный файл структуры Page одна за другой. Запись вроде как проходит, но чтение не удаётся. (в комментарии я указал как выводил данные в файл).Выдаёт `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    long id;        // id of page
    char* title;    // title of page
    char** links;   // dynamic array of URLs
}
Page;

const int pageSize = sizeof(Page);


Page* create(long id, char* title, int number)
{
    Page* res = (Page*)malloc(sizeof(Page) );
    (*res).id = id;
    (*res).title = title;
    (*res).links = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * number);

    return res;
}

int insert(Page* pg, FILE* output)
{
    if (fwrite(pg, pageSize, 1, output) != 0 )
        return 0;
    else
        return -1;
}

Page* read(FILE* input)
{
    Page * ptr;

    if (fread(ptr, pageSize, 1, input) != 0 )
        return ptr;
    else
        return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /*
    FILE* f = fopen("data.bin", "wb");

    Page* pg = create(1, "Book store", 10);
    insert(pg, f);
    pg = create(2, "Laptops", 12);
    insert(pg, f);
    pg = create(3, "TVs", 15);
    insert(pg, f);
    */

    FILE* f = fopen("data.bin", "rb");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        Page* pg = read(f);
        printf("%s\n", (*pg).title );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: fseek в начале лишний

Comment: Не решило проблему

Comment: Конечно! :) `Page * ptr;  if (fread(ptr, p...` куда вы читаете данные!? память то кто выделять будет?

Comment: Разве fread не выделяет память и не возвращает адрес выделенной памяти ?

Comment: Смотрите мой ответ, я привел пример. А [fread](http://www.c-cpp.ru/content/fread) конечно не обучен чего либо выделять, что явно из его названия :)

Comment: @Антон "но как я выяснил из английского стэка (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605839/c-and-c-file-i-o), файловый ввод-вывод в C++ медленнее чем в C" - вы точно прочитали все комментарии и ответы в приведённом вопросе?

Answer (score 1):

Чтоб не зависить от выравнивания которое придумает компилятор нужно завернуть структуру в такую конструкцию

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
typedef {...
}...;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

В структуре объявлен массив указателей `**` а указатель это число указывающее на данные, а не сами данные. То есть сами данные вы в файл не записали. А при чтении обращаетесь к невыделенной памяти.

Comment: Помимо того, что мне нужно поставить две pragma и закрыть файл (забыл), что ещё сделать ? Как структуру описать, чтоб в ней хранились динамические данные ? Мне кажется судя по коду понятен мой замысел

Comment: Динамические данные лучше писать в файл по стандарту, например asn.1, если делать самому, то надо проектировать содержимое файла, где хеадеры с размером и позициями, где сами данные..

Comment: @Антон если не для микроконтроллера пишите - то возьмите xml, json, bson . выбор большой

Comment: @eri, а если я хочу больше суток индексировать Сеть 50 потоками одновременно ?

Comment: @Антон `msgpack` вполне компактный и парсится быстро. можно соорудить свой протокол, в котором обычно пишется 1-2 байта длинна строки, потом строка, длинна, строка.. собирается-разбирается циклами

Answer (score 1):

```
Page * ptr;
if (fread(ptr, pageSize, 1, input) != 0 )
```

**Куда** вы хотите читать? В `ptr` - какой-то мусор, т.е. он указывает не пойми куда - и в это не пойми куда вы пытаетесь писать информацию :(

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/322688)

Comment: @Эникейщик Если вы в состоянии только глотать полностью пережеванную кашку - это еще не основание считать других такими же :) Я всегда стараюсь отвечать именно так - чтобы человек **САМ** додумал до конца. Жаль, что у вас нет такой привычки - не писать ответы, а додумывать самому...

Comment: Первое предложение опускает этот комментарий на уровень школоты - приопустил другого и рад. Был такой скетч с Галустяном, где он написал в каментах "кино - говно" и после этого власть чувствует, мощь. Вот тут то же самое, похоже.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае фатальная ошибка в чтении в неинециализированную переменную `ptr` в функции `read`

```
Page* read(FILE* input)
{
    Page * ptr = malloc(sizeof(Page));
    if (!ptr)
        return NULL;
    if (fread(ptr, 1, sizeof(*ptr), input) == sizeof(*ptr))
        return ptr;

    free(ptr);
    return NULL;
}
```

Вот так попробуйте, и `fseek` уберите в `main` - он там не нужен.

Comment: Вместо new скорее malloc - в C нет new

Comment: Ну или так, можно и calloc, чтоб мусор убрать,для эстетики :)

Comment: Ваша реализация функции read не помогла

Comment: Segmentation fault теперь нет - выводит `T` и две пустые строки

Comment: :) кому не помогла? Поправьте свой вариант, как вы поправили.

Comment: Посмотрите, логику размеров поправил, в соответствии с С синтаксисом

Comment: Опять тоже самое: `T` и две пустые строки (всего три строки в выводе)

Comment: А что там в файле то? его же надо сперва записать идентичной структурой, а потом только читать. Я вот невижу не одногоместа где бы записывался данный файл, и линки из структуры по любому записаны не будут, их надо писать отдельно

Comment: Напиши плз как писать линки

Comment: https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1 это обширный вопрос , и требует определенной квалификации, посмотрите примеры, возьмите готовую библиотеку